# Fit gaussian mixture model to PDF

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As the title says I want to fit a gaussian mixture model to a given PDF. So, suppose I know the probability density distribution of my data and let's just say it is discretised like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gaussian(gx, amp, mu, sig):
    return amp * np.exp(-np.power(gx - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
g1 = gaussian(gx=x, amp=2, mu=-3, sig=1)
g2 = gaussian(gx=x, amp=1, mu=4, sig=0.5)
pdf = (g1 + g2) / np.nansum(g1 + g2)

plt.scatter(x, pdf)
plt.show()
```

this gives us a nice pdf with two separat gaussian peaks. Now I simply want to fit a gaussian mixture model to the pdf. The way I understand scikit works is that you don't fit the model to a pdf, but to data samples. So, in principle I would have to take the pdf, draw samples from it and then fit gaussian mixture models, but I already have the pdf and just want to describe it with a mixture of gaussians...

any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean "Now I simply want to fit a gaussian mixture model to the pdf"? The pdf you created is already a mixture of gaussians. Are you asking *how* to draw samples from it?

Comment: I am interested in solving the same problem (working from PDF not from samples). Since my "PDF" is discrete (really it's like a histogram) I thought about generating samples from it by injecting the center value of each bin according to its frequency (e.g. if I had a histogram like 1:3, 2:6, 3:5, 4: 2 then I could generate the sequence [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4]) but I think there is probably a "smarter"/better way. Would you mind posting an answer showing what you ended up doing?

Comment: I have same question encountered. Have you solved that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need a `curve_fit`, not a sklearn GMM. Should do the job just as good. However, if you have more than 2 Gaussians and they are not well separated, you will need a good initial parameter guess.